# Using MediaInfo.dll with lua?

Tags: dll, lua, mediainfo

Is there any code to get media tags using mediainfo.dll in lua programming , if there is a way to call the dll , how you'd return it's args??

Comment: Have you looked at Alien? http://alien.luaforge.net/

Comment: as stated previously, you could write a little alien wrapper (http://alien.luaforge.net/) or a ffi wrapper (http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html) which is part of the luajit interpreter or write an "ordinary" C-binding. There is no build in functionality for the standard Lua interpreter to make calls to dll (win) or so (unix).